# Dynamic WHERE condition Is Null or Is Not Null

Tags: t-sql

I have a stored procedure which takes a `@flag` as a parameter. That flag supposes to indicate to select null values or none null values.

for none null values my solution looks like that:

```
@Flag int
SET @Flag = NULL

WHERE   ISNULL(column1,'') = ISNULL(@Flag,'')
```

Is there a way to accommodate none null values in similar manner ? If no what would be the most compact solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Flag int
SET @Flag = NULL

select * from table
WHERE (@flag is null and column is null) or ((@flag is not null and column is not null) and @flag = column)
```

I advise to NEVER SET ANSI_NULL OFF, NEVER! That can lead to a lot of unnecessary maintenance pain.

No need for a compact solution like

```
ISNULL(column1,'') = ISNULL(@Flag,'')
```

Also that ill return null rows when @flag = '' and also ill return '' rows when flag is null

Comment: That works perfect, I was searching in the wrong direction :). Will save me lot of time and headache of not working with string SQL. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is SET ANSI_NULL OFF and then do comparison: column1 = @flag

Comment: That solution will not let me accommodating none null values a it requires to change `=` to not equal condition `<>`.

Comment: Why do you have to change = to not equal? Just do a straight comparison column1 = @flag

Comment: Oh wait, are you comparing column1 with @flag, or just want to filter null and not null by column1?

Comment: I want to compare the `@flag` with the column1, so for example if  @flag is null (or has specific value) to select null values, otherwise to select none null values.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get it: "If @flag is null (or has specific value), select null values". This is equivalent to select null values no matter what. Can you please clarify?

Comment: The @Flag suppose to indicate to select `null` or `none null` values. So for example if I execute the `SP` with `@Flag = 1` then I want to select `none null` values, if the `@flag = 0` or `null `I want to select `null` values.

Comment: From microsoft: In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.